# MySql create table error expexting REFERENCES

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

Here is my code, i get an error at the very last line (syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting REFERENCES)

```
CREATE TABLE `MyDB`.`Product`(
`Product_ID` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Category_ID` int(2),
`Supplier_VAT` int(10),
`Product_Name` varchar(20),
`Description` varchar(300),
KEY (`Product_ID`),
PRIMARY KEY (`Product_ID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`Category_ID`,`Supplier_VAT`)
);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I figured, that the error is caused by the foreign key line, still don't know why though. :/

Comment: a `FOREIGN KEY` must reference another table. That's what FKs are for.

Comment: Yeah i just figured it out, that's what a reference means anyway, i fill kind of stupid xD. Thanks anyway :P

Comment: If you have a `Category` table (probably with `Category_ID` and `Supplier_VAT` columns), add that `CREATE TABLE` as well in the question.

Comment: The usual road in this site is: Either post an answer with the solution you found (and accept) or delete the question (if it is too simple.) Don't edit the question with *"Solved"*

Comment: Ok i'll keep it in mind, thanks, but i wont delete it know since it has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...    
FOREIGN KEY (`Category_ID`,`Supplier_VAT`) REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name_1, index_col_name_2)
```

should fix your problem!

Comment: yeah thanks as ypercube already answered , i should have added the most obvious thing missing, a reference thanks for your reply anyway.